# Horizontal navigation bar / dropdown content does not appear on hover as excepted. Thanks

Tags: html, css

```
 <style>

.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    left:24vw;

        }
.listitem  { 

        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0.5vw;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 8vw;
        float: left;
        list-style-type: none;
        z-index:1;
        background-color:green;
         }

.listitem:hover {
            background-color: red;

}
li {
list-style-type: none;

}
```

Here I put in display that this section/first item of nav bar  does not appear by default.

```
    .ddc1  { 

    position: absolute;
    top: 5.3vh;
    left: 0vw;
    display: none;
    width: 7.1vw;
    z-index:999;




}
```

Here I put in display that this section/the second item of nav bar  does not appear by default.

```
    .ddc2  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.2vh;
    left: 9.2vw;
    display:none;
    width: 7.1vw;
    z-index:999;

}

.ddc1 li, .ddc2 li {background-color: yellow;}
.ddc1 li, .ddc2 li { 

                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 2vh 2vw; }
```

So here is the code that I hoped will work for showing dropdown content on hover.

```
    .drpdm1:hover .ddc1 {display: block;}
    .drpdm2:hover .ddc2 {display: block;}


    </style>
```

Here is a nav bar that I am trying to create.

```
        <ul class="navbar">
<li class="listitem" class="drpdm1"><a>123456</a></li>
  <ul class="ddc1">
    <li><a>123456</a></li>
    <li><a>123456</a></li>
    <li><a>123456</a></li>
  </ul> 
<li class="listitem" class="drpdm2"><a>654321</a></li>
  <ul class="ddc2">
    <li><a>123456</a></li>
    <li><a>123456</a></li>
    <li><a>123456</a></li>
  </ul>
<li class="listitem"><a>7891911</a></li>
<li class="listitem"><a>1231231</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you an example:

```
<li class="listitem">
<a>123456</a>
  <ul class="ddc1">
    <li><a>123456</a></li>
    <li><a>123456</a></li>
    <li><a>123456</a></li>
  </ul> 
</li>
```

and in the CSS, to reach ddc1 on `listitem` hover:

```
.listitem:hover .ddc1  {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to have the nested `<ul>` elements between the opening and closing `<li>` tags, like this:

```html
<ul class="navbar">
    <li class="listitem" class="drpdm1"><a>123456</a>
        <ul class="ddc1">
            <li><a>123456</a></li>
            <li><a>123456</a></li>
            <li><a>123456</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="listitem" class="drpdm2"><a>654321</a>
        <ul class="ddc2">
            <li><a>123456</a></li>
            <li><a>123456</a></li>
            <li><a>123456</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="listitem"><a>7891911</a></li>
    <li class="listitem"><a>1231231</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. This definitely might be one of the errors but it seems that there are others as well because it is still not working.